# Can someone help me on my Hangman game?

Tags: java

Okay here is what I have now, and I still can't get it to work :(. I got it to work if you lost but it still wont say you won even though I added a string that checks to see if it equaled the length for you to win

```
static String[] words = new String[] { "turtle","hamster","rabbit","potato",
    "carrot","mouse","dog","cat","applejuice","milk","cow"};
static char[] dashes;
static String randomWord;
static int wrongGuesses;
static int playLoop;
static int lettersRight;
static boolean gameWon = false;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out
    .println("Do you want to play?, Enter 1 to play or 0 to quit");

    playLoop = input.nextInt();

    if (playLoop == 0) {
        System.out.println(":'(, The console is sad :'(");
    } else if (playLoop > 0) {
        System.out.println("The Game Has Started!");
        playLoop();
    }
}
public static void hangMan() {
    if (wrongGuesses == 0) {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|");
        System.out.println("|");
        System.out.println("|");
    } else if (wrongGuesses == 1) {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|        O");
        System.out.println("|");
        System.out.println("|");
    } else if (wrongGuesses == 2) {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|        O");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|");
    } else if (wrongGuesses == 3) {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|        O");
        System.out.println("|      --|");
        System.out.println("|");
    } else if (wrongGuesses == 4) {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|        O");
        System.out.println("|      --|--");
        System.out.println("|");
    } else if (wrongGuesses == 5) {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|        O");
        System.out.println("|      --|--");
        System.out.println("|       /");
    } else if (wrongGuesses == 6) {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|        O");
        System.out.println("|      --|--");
        System.out.println("|       / \\");
    } else if (wrongGuesses == 7) {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("|        |");
        System.out.println("|        O");
        System.out.println("|      --|--");
        System.out.println("|      _/ \\");
    }
}

private static void playLoop() {

    randomWord = getWord();
    int guessesLeft = 8;
    System.out.println(randomWord);
    for (int x = 0; x < randomWord.length(); x++) {
        dashes[x] = '_';
    }

    wrongGuesses = 0;
    String usedLetters = "";

    while (wrongGuesses < 8) {
        if (guessesLeft < 2) {
            System.out.println("You have " + guessesLeft + " guess left.");
        } else {
            System.out
            .println("You have " + guessesLeft + " guesses left.");
        }
        System.out.println("Guess a letter!");
        for (int y = 0; y < randomWord.length(); y++) {
            System.out.print(dashes[y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        char userGuess = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (!checkGuess(userGuess)) {
            guessesLeft--;
            wrongGuesses++;
        }
        if (checkGuess(userGuess)){
            lettersRight ++;
        }
        if (lettersRight == randomWord.length()) {
            gameWon = true;
            }
        if (wrongGuesses == 8){
            System.out.println("----------");
            System.out.println("|        |");
            System.out.println("|        O");
            System.out.println("|      --|--");
            System.out.println("|      _/ \\_");
            System.out.println("Your friend is dead :(");
            System.out.println();
            main(new String[1]);
        }
        hangMan();
        usedLetters += userGuess + " ";
        System.out.println("Guessed Letters ---> "
                + usedLetters);
    }

}

private static String getWord() {
    int randomNum = (int) ((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    randomWord = words[randomNum];
    dashes = new char[randomWord.length()];
    return randomWord;
}

private static boolean checkGuess(char userGuess) {
    boolean correct = false;
    for (int z = 0; z < randomWord.length(); z++) {
        if (userGuess == randomWord.charAt(z)) {
            dashes[z] = userGuess;
            correct = true;
        }
    }
    return correct;
}
public static void win(){
    if (gameWon) {
        System.out.println("Congrats You Won The Game");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean it also puts a square where a dash is supposed to go? are you able to post an image?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are trying to print out "Congrats you won the game" -- are you saying you need help with the logic to determine when a player has won the game?

Comment: Two problems: Your while loop is only checking number of wrong guesses, not if you won, and you are not calling your win() method.  Change the loop to `while (!gameWon && wrongGuesses < 8)` then call `win()` as soon as the loop exits.

Comment: Counting problem: Your `lettersRight` counter only increments once per guess so any word with double letters like 'Potato' will only count the first letter.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I got it, i showed my teacher and he said it was alright :D

Answer (score 1):

As far as getting your program to say "Congrats", I don't see any logic to determine when the game is won.  It looks like the game will keep going until you get 8 wrong guesses, even after the word is completed.  A simple way to add that logic would be a boolean and a counter to keep track of how many letters have been guessed.

Suggestions: Added code to display incorrect guesses when prompting for the next guess.  Added code to keep players from cheating by guessing the same letter repeatedly.

```
static boolean gameWon = false;
static int lettersRight = 0;
static char[] wrongLetters = new char[8];

private static void playLoop() {
    ....
    // include boolean in loop condition so it can exit when won
    while (wrongGuesses < 8 && !gameWon) {
    ....
        System.out.println("Guess a letter!");
        for (int y = 0; y < randomWord.length(); y++) {
            System.out.print(dashes[y] + " ");
        }

        // display previous guesses
        System.out.println("Wrong guesses!");
        for (int w = 0; w < wrongGuesses; w++) {
            System.out.print(wrongLeters[w] + " ");
        }

        char userGuess = input.next().charAt(0);

        // verify guess is a new letter
        if (!alreadyGuessed(userGuess)) {
            if (!checkGuess(userGuess)) {
                guessesLeft--;
                wrongGuesses++;
                // add incorrect guesses to an array 
                wrongLetters[wrongGuesses] = userGuess;
            }
            else {
                // check counter against length and set boolean
                if (lettersRight == randomWord.length()) {
                gameWon = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No Cheating! That letter has already been used."); 
        }
    ....
    // check if game was won or lost after the while loop exits
    if (gameWon) {
        System.out.println("Congrats You Won The Game");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Your friend is dead :(");
    }
    ....
}

private static boolean checkGuess(char userGuess) {
    boolean correct = false;
    for (int z = 0; z < randomWord.length(); z++) {
        if (userGuess == randomWord.charAt(z)) {
            dashes[z] = userGuess;
            correct = true;
            // increase counter inside for loop so any letters
            // occurring more than once are all counted
            letterRight++; 
        }
    }
    return correct;
}

// method to compare user input already correct letter guesses
// this prevents users from cheating by using the same letter repeatedly
private static boolean alreadyGuessed(char userGuess) {
    boolean used= false;
    for (int q = 0; q < randomWord.length(); q++) {
        if (userGuess == dashes(q)) {
            used = true;
        }
    }
    return used;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it print out a message when the user guesses the word you would need to have it check each time at the end of the game loop to see if they guessed it correctly then use a selection statement to process it if they did.

This is necessary anyway since you wouldn't want them to continue being able to guess the word after they won.